# jquery display dialog during page initialization

Tags: jquery

How can I have a jqueryui dialog display "Loading" at the beginning of document.ready (or sooner) and then have it disappear at the end of document.ready.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this it will work in all the browsers even if they are slow in javascript execution like IE 6/7

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("LoadingContainer").dialog('open');

  setTimeout(function(){
    //Put all the stuff here which you want to execute on load

    //Finally close the loading dialog
    $("LoadingContainer").dialog('close');

  }, 400);

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Set and show your dialog right after the `body` tag and dismiss it when document.ready.

Answer (score 0):

I would have an element that displays the message, and simply hide it when the document.ready is ready.  For example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // All other loading items
    $("#loadingMessage").hide();
});
```

Make sure you put the hide() function as the last, that way everything else loads first.

Comment: Be sure to style #loadingMessage appropriately and by default set the display to something visible.